# ElasticSearch withJava API - Mapping a complicated class with from a class or existing object

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My class - "Transaction", is complicated with a lot of nested objects.
There is a way to define the mapping straight from the class or an existing object?

note: I am using the rest API with High-Level client.
if there is only a solution with the low-level client, ist also ok.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean straight from the class? I could see, how complicated object could be converted to mapping request, however, you still need to have some logic around field types

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no way to define the mapping straight from the class or an existing object.
What I did, is to convert every object to a JSON String, and store it as one String field.

code:

```
// Using jackson
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String transactionAsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(transaction); 
clientService.insertObjectToDb(transactionData.getHash(), transactionAsJson, 
             TRANSACTION_INDEX_NAME,  TRANSACTION_OBJECT_NAME );

public String insertObjectToDb(Hash hash, String objectAsJsonString, String index, String objectName) throws IOException {
        IndexResponse indexResponse = null;
        try {
            IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(
                    index,
                    INDEX_TYPE,
                    hash.toString());
            request.source((jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field(objectName, objectAsJsonString)
                    .endObject()));
            indexResponse = restClient.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            return indexResponse.toString();
        }
    }
```